# css grid table with equal size columns and header

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a table with equal size header and content columns, in real use case I will be generating the content dynamically so I can't just use 12 equal size columns.

How can I get the columns in both the `header` and `section` to be equal widths?

https://codepen.io/thomas159/pen/wvgwrNO

**html**

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="header">
     <div class="cell">
      heading 1 
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      heading 2
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      heading 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
   
     <div class="cell">
    1
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    this content stretches
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    3
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    4
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
      this content stretches
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    6
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    7
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
      this content stretches
    </div>
       <div class="cell">
    9
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.grid {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
}

.cell {
  background: #ff00ff;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 
 .header{
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    -ms-grid-columns: auto auto 1fr;
    padding-bottom: rem-calc(5px);
 }
 
 .section {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto ;
    padding-bottom: rem-calc(5px);
   height: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the power of CSS grid to create a table with columns that have equal length.

This is the html:

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">
      heading 1 
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      heading 2
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      heading 3
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    1
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    this content stretches
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    3
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    4
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
      this content stretches
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    6
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
    7
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
      this content stretches
    </div>
       <div class="cell">
    9
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.cell {
  background: #ff00ff;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
 }
```

Explanation: the CSS property `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)` lets you create a table of three columns of equal length. If you want to increase the number of columns of your table dynamically, you can use JavaScript to change the number "3" to 4, or 5, and so forth.

This is a picture of the final result: [image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work 200% just have to edit it to what you really want.

```
<div class="main_container">
    <div class="gridcontainer">
        <div class='grids'>
        <!--- add this if you want to add title to your boxes else just ignore-->

            <div class='gridtitle'></div>

         <!--- Title ends here-->
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

Note that you have to duplicate the gridbox on main_container to text result.
Here's is the css for this html

```
.main_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    border: 0px solid red;
    justify-content: center;
}

.gridcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid white;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}

.grids {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    background: rgba(86, 70, 0, 0.2);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 52);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* to add a title use */
.title {
    width: 98%;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0px solid grey;
    margin-left: 5px;
    opacity: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 25);
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 40%;
    width: 60%;
}
```